# "Clean unable 46" message on Brother DCP 145c printer

Tags: maintenance, inkjet-printer, brother-printer

The LCD screen on my Brother DCP 145c printer shows a message

> clean unable 46

I changed cartridges and the printer does not respond on pressing the buttons. What shall I do?

Answer (score 1):

Try to [reset](http://comptechreview.com/2011/05/25/how-to-reset-brother-dcp-110c-115c-120c-130c-135c-145c-150c-165c-185c-dcp-195c-printer/) it

> 1. Press the Menu, then Mono Start key then press the UP arrow key 4 times to make the machine enter the maintenance mode and “ERROR 46″
>      pops-up in the display.
> 2. Enter maintenance mode 80: Select 8 by pressing the UP/DOWN arrow key and push OK key and select 0 and push OK key
> 3. Now Press MONO arrow key several times until you see PURGE:XXXXX
> 4. Select 2 and push OK, Select 7 and push OK, 8 and push OK, select 3 and push OK and the purge counter is now reset to 00000.
> 5. Press STOP/EXIT key to go to root of maintenance mode
> 6. Enter code 99 to exit maintenance mode: Select 9 and push OK, Select 9 and push OK.

Answer (score 0):

according to [Brother website error code listing](http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/BSC/public/eu/eu_ot/en/faq/faq/000000/000100/000068/faq000168_005.html?reg=eu&c=eu_ot&lang=en&prod=dcp145c_eu_as)

error code 46 refers to "ink absorber pad is full and needs replacing."

You will need to bring it in for service